# Stack architecture flutter

Tags: flutter, architecture, stack, containers

I'm new on Flutter and I have some problem with my architecture.

I want the following stack :

```
TabBar
```

---

```
DropDownMenu
```

---

```
ListView
```

Indeed, I currently have

```
Tabbar
```

---

`Dropdown Menu` (start at the same height as `ListView`)

`ListView` (start at the same height as `DropDown Menu`)

My snippet for `DropDown Menu` and `ListView` is the following :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          buildFixHeaderDropdownMenu(),
          new TaskListView(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I want the following screen :
[image: desiredUI]

**But right now I have this screen :**
[image: currentUI]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found another logic code as follows :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          buildFixHeaderDropdownMenu(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

Widget buildFixHeaderDropdownMenu() {
    return new DefaultDropdownMenuController(
        child: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        buildDropdownHeader(),
        new Expanded(
            child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new TaskListView(),//LISTVIEW HERE
            buildDropdownMenu()
          ],
        ))
      ],
    ));
  }
```